# Foreach tags-input Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-tags-input

estoy haciendo la edición de un formulario. Tengo un input que se llama opciones que esta conectado a una tabla y relacionada con la de los productos. Bien cuando edite el producto necesito que me muestre dentro del `value` todas las opciones que tiene este producto.

En mi controlador obtengo las opciones que tiene este producto de este modo.

```
$opciones = Opcion::where('product_id', $id )->get();
return view("admin.edit_producto")->with(["opciones" => $opciones]);
```

El input-tag en el formulario es el siguiente:

```
<div class="col-8">
    @foreach ($opciones as $option)
        <input type="text" value="{{ $option->listado }}" data-role="tagsinput" id="opciones" name="opciones[]" class="form-control">
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Evidentemente lo que hace este foreach es replicar la linea y me sale en bucle, según la cantidad de opciones que encuentra en este producto. Pero como hago que me lo imprima dentro del value y no repita la fila.

Añado foto para que se comprenda mejor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

**Probe del siguiente modo**

```
  <input  type="text" data-role="tagsinput" value="
   @foreach ($productos->opciones as $option)
     {{ $option->listado}},
   @endforeach
   " id="opciones" name="opciones[]" class="form-control">
```

Funciona bien, le añadi una coma para que se separen, pero no se si es una forma correcta.

**Edito:** No es una buena idea por que lo envia todo en una misma fila y tiene que ser en distintas filas

Comment: No se entiende la duda, ¿editas y explicas mejor por favor?

Comment: Hola @BetaM  que tal? la duda es que no se como imprimir todos los valores que hay en `value`

Comment: En tu vista o en donde?

Comment: En la vista de editar producto, en el input tiene que cargar los values @BetaM , añadi una foto a la pregunta para que se entienda mejor

Comment: Los tags tienen que cargarse en el mismo input, pero si hago un foreach hace ciclo del input tambien, y no tiene que ser así @BetaM

Comment: Entiendo, déjame ver que puedo hacer

Comment: Hola @BetaM como esta relacionado, como hago un bucle en el controlador para que escriba tantas filas como sea necesario, intento de este modo pero no hace nada `foreach ($opcion as $opt) {
            $opt = new Opcion;
            $opt->product_id= $id;
            $opt->listado= $request->input('opciones');

            $opcion->save();
        }` que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Qué contiene exactamente `$opciones`? Es un arreglo de tags o un arreglo de strings en donde cada uno tiene los tags separados por coma? Si es lo primero, haz la prueba cerrando el input con `</input>` en cada bucle

Comment: Hola @BetaM he cambiado la forma de hacerlo ya que así no le encontraba la solución, pero ahora tengo una duda en la forma que la estoy haciendo, que hago borro esta pregunta y creo otra, o bien modifico esta misma??

Comment: porque en un input? y no en un select?

Comment: Hola @Dohko19 al final lo hice de otro modo, si puede hecharle un vistazo aquí te lo agradeceria https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/367514/rellena-inputs-con-javascritpt-sql-laravel