# Rellena inputs con JavaScritpt SQL - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

estoy haciendo la edición de los productos con un formulario. He añadido una apartado en el formulario que se llama opciones, que eta conectado a una tabla realacionada con la de productos.

Bien, lo que he hecho es que en este campo podamos añadir 2 opciones más, es decir a cada producto le puedo tener 3 opciones. Esto esta echo con Javascritp.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var MaxInputs       = 2; //maximum extra input boxes allowed
    var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
    var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
    var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added
    
    //on add input button click
    $(AddButton).click(function (e) {
            //max input box allowed
            if(x <= MaxInputs) {
                FieldCount++; //text box added ncrement
                //add input box
                $(InputsWrapper).append('<div style="position:relative;"><input type="text" class="form-control formNuevo marbTn2" name="opciones[]" id="field_'+ FieldCount +'"/> <a href="#" class="removeclass"><i class="far fa-trash-alt eye"></i></a></div>');
                x++; //text box increment
                
                $("#AddMoreFileId").show();
                
                $('AddMoreFileBox').html("Add field");
                
                // Delete the "add"-link if there is 3 fields.
                if(x == 3) {
                    $("#AddMoreFileId").hide();
                     $("#lineBreak").html("<br>");
                }
            }
            return false;
    });
    
    $("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            if( x > 1 ) {
                    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
                    x--; //decrement textbox
                
                    $("#AddMoreFileId").show();
                
                    $("#lineBreak").html("");
                
                    // Adds the "add" link again when a field is removed.
                    $('AddMoreFileBox').html("Add field");
            }
        return false;
    }) 
    
    });
```

Esto a la vez le añade un botón de eliminar a cada fila y una vez que hay 3 opciones ya no se pueden añadir más filas. Bien esto cuando guardo el producto lo hago del siguiente modo.

```
    foreach($request->opciones as $key => $value){
                $opt = new Opcion;
                $opt->product_id= $id;
                $opt->listado= $request->opciones[$key];
    
                $opt->save();
            }
```

Esa es la parte que me guarda las opciones en la tabla opciones. Bien pero a la hora de editar el producto necesito que me cargue dinamicamente las opciones que tiene el producto, del mismo modo, si hay 3 ya no se pueden añadir más, etc.. al final que tenga el mismo funcionamiento que crea el JavaScript. Esto como lo puedo hacer???? gracias.

**Prueba**

Intento de la siguiente forma, creando un ciclo y así que también incremente el valor de `field_`. Si me saca los resultados, pero el javascript no detecta que hay elementos ya, entonces puedo seguir añadiendo dos elementos más y los que hay no los puedo borrar.

```
    @php $number = 1;@endphp
    
       <div id="InputsWrapper">
         @forelse ($productos->opciones as $opt)
           <div><input type="text" name="opciones[]" id="field_@php echo $number++ @endphp" value=" {{ $opt->listado }} " class="form-control formNuevo marbTn2"></div>
         @empty
            <div><input type="text" name="opciones[]" id="field_1" value="" class="form-control formNuevo marbTn2"></div>
         @endforelse
        </div>
        <div id="AddMoreFileId">
            <a href="#" id="AddMoreFileBox" class="btn btn-info pull-right addfila">Añadir fila</a><br><br>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente sólo necesitas rescatar la cantidad de opciones que tiene cada producto. Algo que puedes hacer es tener un input oculto para guardar la cantidad, algo así:

```
<input type="hidden" id="cantidadOpciones" data-cantidad="{{ count($productos->opciones) }}">

<div id="InputsWrapper">
    ...         
</div>
```

Internamente, en tu Javascript, harías algo así:

```
...
var x = $("#cantidadOpciones").attr('data-cantidad'); // Cantidad actual de opciones del producto

// Si ya tiene las 3 opciones
// Ocultas el boton de agregar más

if(x == 3) {
    $("#AddMoreFileId").hide();
    $("#lineBreak").html("<br>");
}

//on add input button click
$(AddButton).click(function (e) {
...
```

Según la lógica que tienes, eso debería ser suficiente.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @L. Flor , me sigue dejando crear dos, ya haya 1,2 o 3 opciones.

Comment: Al parecer `FieldCount` también debe ser actualizado, perdona, es que no me quedó  muy claro para qué servía cada variable.

Comment: Baje el `var` más abajo y ya no me deja añadir más si ya hay 3, y si solo hay dos solo me deja una. Pero hay algo que el javascript hacia, si ya hay 3 opciones el botón de añadir fila desaparecia y la primera opción no, pero las otras dos se pueden eliminar para cambiarlas, como puedo hacer que aparezca el botón de eliminar tal como actuaba el javascript? @L. Flor

Comment: Bueno lo del botón de eliminar lo arregle añadiendo esto que tenia el JavaScript en el input donde hacemos el foreach `<a href="#" class="removeclass"><i class="far fa-trash-alt eye"></i></a>` Solo faltaria ocultar el botón de añadir fila si es que ya hay 3 opciones. @L. Flor

Comment: Esa es una comparación que ya haces, sólo que también debes hacerla al inicio. Ya actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: Brillante!! Funciona perfecto, a ver si puedes ver la otra pregunta que te pase, es la que mas tiempo lleva parada, muchas gracias has hecho mucho por mi hoy!! Gracias @L.Flor